# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{e^{-\pi s}+ 2 + s}{s^2 +2s + 2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of:

$F(S) = \frac{e^{-\pi s}+ 2 + s}{s^2 +2s + 2}$.

I really have no idea how to approach this, since I cannot use partial fractions decomposition of the denominator.

Comment: Complete the square.

Comment: This might by a silly question, but what do you mean?

Comment: Put the denominator in the form $(s+a)^2+b$ where $a,b$ are real numbers. Searching up 'complete the square' will give plenty of results.

Comment: By doing this, I can see how to find the inverse of $\frac{s+2}{(s+ 2)^2 +2}$, but not how to find the inverse of $\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{(s+2)^2 +2}$

Comment: *Mathematica* gives:  $\frac{1}{2} e^{(-1-i) t} \left(i e^{\pi } \left(-1+e^{2 i t}\right) \theta (t-\pi )+(1-i)
   e^{2 i t}+(1+i)\right)$ where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=completing+the+square&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{-\pi s}+ 2 + s}{s^2 +2s + 2}\right)$$
$$=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2 +2s + 2}\right)+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s+2}{s^2 +2s + 2}\right)\tag1$$
Now $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s+2}{s^2 +2s + 2}\right)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+ 1}\right)+\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{(s+1)^2+ 1}\right)=e^{-t}~\cos t~+~e^{-t}~\sin t$$and $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{e^{-\pi s}}{s^2 +2s + 2}\right)=\text{H}\left(t-\pi \right)e^{-\left(t-\pi \right)}\sin \left(t-\pi \right)\qquad \text{(by second shifting property )}$$

where $~H(x)=\begin{cases}1 & ,\text{if} ~~~~~x\ge 0\\0 &,\text{if} ~~~~~x\lt 0\end{cases}~$ be the Heaviside function.

Now from $(1)$ , $$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}=e^{-t}~\cos t~+~e^{-t}~\sin t~+~\text{H}\left(t-\pi \right)e^{-\left(t-\pi \right)}\sin \left(t-\pi \right)$$

---

**Remarks:**

- $$\mathcal{L}=\{e^{at}\}=\frac{1}{p-a}\implies \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{1}{p-a}\right\}=e^{at}$$
- $$\mathcal{L}=\{\sin(at)\}=\frac{a}{p^2+a^2}\implies \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{a}{p^2+a^2}\right\}=\sin(at)$$
- $$\mathcal{L}=\{\cos(at)\}=\frac{p}{p^2+a^2}\implies \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{p}{p^2+a^2}\right\}=\cos(at)$$

> **Second Shifting Property:** If $~\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(p)\right\}
> =f(t)~$, then $~\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(p)~e^{-ap}\right\}
> =g(t)~$ where $$~g(t)=\begin{cases}  f(t-a) \quad \text{if} ~~~t~\gt~a\\ 0 \quad ~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{if} ~~~t~\lt ~a\end{cases}~$$

which can also be written as  $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{e^{-ap}~F(p)\}=f(t-a)~H(t-a)$$
where $~H(x)=\begin{cases}1 & ,\text{if} ~~~~~x\ge 0\\0 &,\text{if} ~~~~~x\lt 0\end{cases}~$ be the Heaviside function.

Answer (score 0):

Break the numerator into three terms and use linearity:

$-\frac{1}{2} i e^{(-1-i) (t-\pi )} \left(-1+e^{2 i (t-\pi )}\right) \theta (t-\pi ), $

$-i e^{(-1-i) t} \left(-1+e^{2 i t}\right),$

and

$\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) e^{(-1-i) t} \left(e^{2 i t}-i\right).$

Add them.