# Find the inverse laplace transform of $\mathcal{L^{-1}}$

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

If $\mathcal{L^{-1}}=\frac{2-2e^{-5s}}{s(s+1)^2}+\frac{e^{-6s}}{(s+1)^2}$, how do I find the inverse Laplace transform? I see that there are fractions for this equation, so I have to use partial fractions here. Now I get $\frac{A}{(s+1)}+\frac{B}{(s+1)^2}$ and $\frac{C}{(s+1)}+\frac{D}{(s+1)^2}$ for the $(s+1)^2$ denominator. What do I do next?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306964/inverse-laplace-transform-of-frace-pi-s-2-ss2-2s-2?rq=1